# \shorttitle error in Elsevier latex template

Tags: errors, els-cas

I am getting this error. Can anyone figure out the error? It will be helpful for me. Thank you in advance.

Undefined control sequence. Please find code below and details here:

[image]

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}

%\usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
%\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{cite}
%\usepackage{float

%%%Author definitions
\def\tsc#1{\csdef{#1}{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}\xspace}}
\tsc{WGM}
\tsc{QE}
\tsc{EP}
\tsc{PMS}
\tsc{BEC}
\tsc{DE}
%%%

\begin{document}
\let\ref\Cref       
\let\eqref\Cref     
\let\autoref\Cref   
\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
\def\textpagefraction{.001}
\shorttitle{CV Radhakrishnan et~al. / Engineering Science and Technology, an International Journal}
%\shortauthors{CV Radhakrishnan et~al.}
\footmarks{\url{https://doi.org/xx.xxxx/j.jestch.20xx.xx.xxx}\\
    2215-0986/\begingroup\tiny{©}\endgroup~20xx Karabuk University. Publishing services by Elsevier B.V.\\
    This is an open access article under the CC BY-NC-ND license (\url{http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/}).
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: to reproduce your problem it would be helpful, if you'd copy the relevant code AND mark it with the '{}' symbol in the editor. I fear nobody here will replicate the code from your sreenshot by hand ;-) // As an unproven guess two candidates to cause thies error are '~' and '/', at least ... I would have preferred checking my guess beforehand, but ... there is no code ... ;-)

Comment: thank you for your reply...code have been updated...kindly see if any there is correction

Comment: Fine. First steps are always the most difficult ones ;-) I tried to retain your question and error indication. My edits are now reviewed by more experienced users here.

Comment: Thanks for your help....hoping to get solutions of it soon

Answer (score 0):

After completing the `\documentcl..`, adding the missing `\end{document}` and installing all missing packages on my computer I see the following:

- don't get the error you reported
- had to change the `\footmark` against `\footnote`
- in the condensed copy of the 1-page printout you see the lonely '1',
  referencing the footnote in text
- besides some minor glitches the footnote is displayed

[image]

To emphasize, here is the relevant change to compile on my computer, without indicating problems for `\shorttitle`; the rest is as in your MWE:

```
\footnote{\url{https://doi.org/xx.xxxx/j.jestch.20xx.xx.xxx}\\
    2215-0986/\begingroup\tiny{©}\endgroup~20xx Karabuk University. Publishing services by Elsevier B.V.\\
    This is an open access article under the CC BY-NC-ND license (\url{http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/}).
}
```

Don't know it that's how it should look like. I used "LuLaTex + display pdf" as options in MiKTeX. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer...But problems still exist.

Comment: I think so, because I could not replicate the error you see. Can it be a matter of options you use or don't use for compile? // Try localizing the trouble-maker,e.g. like this:  delete or comment out larger parts by "halfening". / I.e. remove upper "half" of suspected code, run, restore and delete other "half". Repeat for the "half", which caused a problem. All code is subjected to this procedure. // Or vice versa replace content of both \shorttitle and \footmark (\footnote?) with oversimplified content, which can not fail. Then extend those text-snippets until you have it as now.

Comment: E.g. oversimplify into \shorttitle{abc} and \footmark{def}. If even this compile fails, the problem lies somewhere else.